# String Comparison and Logical OR operation

Tags: java, string

I was wondering how I could say `or` in an `if` statement, when comparing strings, not integers or booleans. I tried using the `||` but I believe that it only works for saying `or` in a Boolean and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
if(string.equals(Rob) || string.equals(Bob))
{
    //do something;
}
```

Comment: `String.equals` returns a boolean.

Comment: are you saying that you want to say `or` instead of `||`?

Comment: String as a variable name? My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: The code *seems* right, assuming `Rob` and `Bob` are the names of other `String` (or `Object`) variables, otherwise if you wanted to compare against the words *Rob* or *Bob*, then you should wrap them using `"` like `"Rob"` and `"Bob"`, as noted in [AntonH's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21505977/1065197).

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I didn't even think that `string` could have been a variable, rather than referring to the class `String`. Maybe this is an entry for code obfuscation?

Comment: @AntonH, My eyes stumbled over it at least three times, before I realised what was going on. It's the sort of shoot yourself and the rest of your team in the foot naming decision that drives me mental.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I've edited my answer to take your comment into account.

Comment: Is there some weird Java thing I'm missing, how can you do equals with one operand?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want ?

```
if(String.equals("Rob") || String.equals("Bob"))
{
    do something;
}
```

If you leave `Rob` or `Bob` without the double-quote marks, it implies that you have variables with those names.

Other than that, `String.equals(...)` returns a boolean.

However, following the comment of Tony Hopkinson, if `string` is the name of the variable, you would have to replace `if(String.equals("Rob") || String.equals("Bob"))` with `if(string.equals("Rob") || string.equals("Bob"))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.equals(Rob) || string.equals(Bob))
{
    //do something;
}
```

Please note string should be a String instance and not the String class.